# Find the last day of the year

Tags: c#, datetime, leap-year

I am doing a task in which it is required to find the last day of the year by given current date.

Like if its 06/Jan/2013 is given to it and it will automatically return the end day of the year.
like 31/Dec/2013

I am using many ways like adding the remaining days of the year, but when it is Leap year then miss matches occurs,
can any body send me precise solution or guied me how to.

Basically I wanted to jump over the last date of the year.This was tentively for C#

Comment: `31st Dec` will always the last day of any year

Comment: `new DateTime(currentDate.Year, 12, 31)`?

Comment: Do you mean it will return 31 Dec 2013? Or does it return the number of days to the end of the year? Don't understand the question...

Comment: This is gold. Favourited.

Comment: Do you mean the day it falls on so like Monday or Saturday??

Comment: No, i only wanted that whatever th edate i enter it returns the last day of the year from mappin gthe current date

Comment: @BibiTahira - Well, now you have plenty of answers to help you with that. For more information, take a look at [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.DateTime.aspx) and specifically this [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx) of it.

Comment: That was nothing like off topic sir, you can see the answers replied by people, if it was then no body should have answered.

Answer (score 20):

Why not something simple like this?

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 1,6);
var lastDayOfTheYear = new DateTime(date.Year, 12, 31);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean Day of Week?

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31).DayOfWeek
```

or more readable:

```
DateTime lastDateOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = lastDateOfYear.DayOfWeek;
```

More about DayOfWeek enum here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Or did you mean how many days left till next year.

```
DateTime lastDateOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);
var daysTillNextYear = (lastDateOfYear - DateTime.Now).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple solution, I have searched many but after many tries, i did with this.

```
DateTime LastDayOfYear(DateTime date)
    {           
        DateTime newdate = new DateTime(date.Year + 1, 1, 1);
        //Substract one year
        return newdate.AddDays(-1);
    }
//Here calling the function 
DateTime current_time = LastDayOfYear(DateTime.Now); // 05,Sep ,2013
// It returned 31, Dec, 2013
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one..
For getting First day and last day..

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
DateTime firstDayyear = new DateTime(year , 1, 1);
DateTime lastDayyear = new DateTime(year , 12, 31);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the date, change the day to 31, the month to December and you have the last day.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last day just use this:

```
string lastdayofyear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12,31).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```